# Exceution ClientScript.RegisterStartup on button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I am currently working on Webforms asp.net and I cant figure out how to execute javascript after button click. Here is my delimer -

I have to show a modal when the button is clicked and return a file from a wcf service , I am using `Response.BinaryWrite(data);` to return the file, but my `age.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "button", "<script>alert('" + "test" + "');</script>");` never works for me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "button", "<script>alert('" + "test" + "');</script>");
```

becomes:

```
string myScript = @"alert('test');"
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "MyScriptName", myScript, true);
```